# Error : ERROR: table name specified more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "queued_items".  The current "user_id" and "item_id" are incorrect, but are stored in the other tables:  users.imported_id and items.imported_id

Trying to grab the imported_id from the other tables and update.  Here's what I tried

```
UPDATE queued_items
SET queued_items.user_id = users.id,
    queued_items.item_id = items.id
FROM queued_items
INNER JOIN users ON queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id
INNER JOIN items ON queued_items.item_id = items.imported_id
```

Getting this error:

```
Error : ERROR:  table name "queued_items" specified more than once
```

Tried removing the FROM line, got this error:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 4: INNER JOIN users ON queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id
         ^
```

I also tried adding an alias to the FROM and JOIN conditions

```
UPDATE queued_items
SET queued_items.user_id = users.id,
    queued_items.item_id = items.id
FROM queued_items as qi
INNER JOIN users ON qi.user_id = users.imported_id
INNER JOIN items ON qi.item_id = items.imported_id
```

Got this error:

```
Error : ERROR:  column "queued_items" of relation "queued_items" does not exist
LINE 2: SET queued_items.user_id = users.id,
            ^
```

Any ideas? (postgres 9)

**PS** Trying to avoid this sub-query:

```
UPDATE queued_items
SET user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id),
    item_id = (SELECT id FROM items WHERE queued_items.item_id = items.imported_id)
```

...because it's crazy slow

Comment: Have you tried using an alias for `queued_items` in the `FROM` clause and the join conditions?

Comment: Just tried that.  I'll update my post with the results.

Comment: Remove `queued_items.` from both parts of the `SET` clause, it's expecting the left sides to always be referring only to columns from the table you're updating.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE queued_items
SET user_id = users.id,
    item_id = items.id
FROM users, items
WHERE queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id
  AND queued_items.item_id = items.imported_id
```

Yeah, old school join conditions.

Comment: Error : ERROR:  column "queued_items" of relation "queued_items" does not exist

Comment: @jmccartie: I think I fixed the SQL. Please try my updated version.

Comment: Could you please explain why this works?

Comment: @DavidWesby Probably best to start with the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Answer (score 6):

[From postgres site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html)

```
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

*from_list*

> A list of table expressions, allowing
>   columns from other tables to appear in
>   the WHERE condition and the update
>   expressions. This is similar to the
>   list of tables that can be specified
>   in the FROM Clause of a SELECT
>   statement. Note that the target table
>   must not appear in the from_list,
>   unless you intend a self-join (in
>   which case it must appear with an
>   alias in the from_list).

Comment: An example of a self-join?

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE queued_items
SET user_id = users.id,
    item_id = items.id
FROM queued_items as QI
INNER JOIN users ON QI.user_id = users.imported_id
INNER JOIN items ON QI.item_id = items.imported_id
```

Comment: The way I interpret the documentation on this: 'queued_items' immediately after the UPDATE is actually treated as an alias when there is also a FROM clause. Technically this query should work as UPDATE QI ... FROM queued_items as QI... So the error is says, "hey, that alias is already implicitly taken". Basically if we only have a where clause, then I don't have to fully qualify the field references with the table at all, but as soon as I introduce a From clause we need to introduce an alias for the table so that the compiler doesn't get confused.

Answer (score 5):

I had to play around with the column/table naming and eventually got it to work. I had to:

- leave out the table name in the destination `SET` columns
- ensure that I aliased the table being updated

Your equivalent would be:

```sql
UPDATE queued_items
SET user_id = users.id,
    item_id = items.id
FROM queued_items as alias_queued_items
INNER JOIN users ON alias_queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id
INNER JOIN items ON alias_queued_items.item_id = items.imported_id
```

instead of:

```sql
UPDATE queued_items
SET queued_items.user_id = users.id,
    queued_items.item_id = items.id
FROM queued_items
INNER JOIN users ON queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id
INNER JOIN items ON queued_items.item_id = items.imported_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sub-query statement and add indexes to those columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps. In my case, what happened was that I `eager loaded` the data and also specified it as data to be joined in `relations`.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to change the name after the `UPDATE` to the alias. Also you can use the aliased names in the set clause. This means that you can set them in your `JOIN` clauses as well.

```
UPDATE qi 
SET qi.user_id = us.id,
    qi.item_id = itms.id
FROM queued_items qi
INNER JOIN users us ON qi.user_id = us.imported_id
INNER JOIN items itms ON qi.item_id = itms.imported_id
```

Comment: Error : ERROR:  relation "qi" does not exist

Answer (score -3):

You don't need the FROM clause. Remove "FROM queued_items" and you are done.

Comment: Removed the from line -->  Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 4: INNER JOIN users ON queued_items.user_id = users.imported_id   (I'll update the post with that error)
        ^